# Disabled Radio Button when mysqli have a data

Tags: php, web

I have a question

I have 4 radio button and 1 input type date

```
<Input type="radio" name="waktu" value="09.00">09.00
<Input type="radio" name="waktu" value="09.20">09.20
<Input type="radio" name="waktu" value="09.40">09.40
<Input type="radio" name="waktu" value="10.00">10.00
<Input type="date" name"tanggal">tanggal
```

Mysqli table is `poliklinikonline` with rows `(id, norm, nama, tanggal, waktu)`

My question is how to disable "a radio button" for each date.

Example :
My table `poliklinikonline` data

```
(id, norm, nama, tanggal, waktu) 
values (1, norm1, nama1, 11/14/2018, 09.00), 
        (2, norm2, nama2, 11/14/2018, 09.20)
```

and this is my code for hide a radio button

```
include "../../controller/koneksi.php";

$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT tanggal FROM polianakonline");

    if(!$query)
    {
        die('error: '. mysqli_error($koneksi));
    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0)
    {
        echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-md-offset-1'>

                <div class=radio>
                    <label>
                        <input type='radio' name='waktu' value='09.00WIB' disabled>
                                    09.00WIB
                        </label>
                </div>
              </div>";
    }else{
        echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-md-offset-1'>

                <div class=radio>
                    <label>
                        <input type='radio' name='waktu' value='09.00WIB'>
                                    09.00WIB
                        </label>
                </div>
              </div>";
    }

?>
```

How to disabled radio button with value "09.00 and 09.20" in date 11/14/2018 and keep enable radio button value "09.00 and 09.20" 11/15/2018? Thank you (^_^)

Comment: Well first you have to query the table to find out which times are there and therefore which times should be disabled

Comment: @RiggsFolly hello I've already set the query, but all of date with radiobutton value "09.00" is disabled when have a data.

Comment: So now you need a while loop, to loop over all the resultset rows